# Core Animation action transition: how do it right

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I make a test project with one view inside of content view of main window. Window have two buttons: appear & disappear. I want animate view appearance when appear button pressed, and animate dissapearance when dissapear button pressed. And I want do this with layer actions.
In other words, I want to make animation every time view added or removed from superview. So, in code I just want to write [parent addSubview:view] or [view removeFromSuperview] and animation should work in that moments. So, Layer Actions seems fits my needs.

Here is app screenshot and [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awtqieukeqc5eul/TestTransitionAnimation.zip) (XCode 4.6):

[image]

**Here is what I did to do that:**

I create a view that will appear/dissapear and add layer action:

```
_coloredView = [[ColoredView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200)];
_coloredView.bgColor = [NSColor yellowColor];
_coloredView.wantsLayer = YES;

// making appear transition from left

CATransition *appearTransition = [CATransition animation];
[appearTransition setDuration:2];
[appearTransition setType:kCATransitionPush];
[appearTransition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[_coloredView.layer addAnimation:appearTransition forKey:kCAOnOrderIn];
```

Then when appear button clicked, I call

```
[contentView addSubview:self.coloredView];
```

When disappear clicked, I call:

```
[self.coloredView removeFromSuperview];
```

And seems some part of things works. The yellow rectangle appears as it should first time. But, here is list of very strange things:

1. I should call `addAnimation:forKey:` every time when button clicked (after view was disappeared), since after first appearing animation will no longer work.
2. Disappear won't work at all (If I try add code after view initialization or before disappear button pressed)
3. When I try to add subview through animator, my transition not work - just default fade-in animation shown.
4. Seems that during movement from left to right some sort of fading works. It's visible when you set duration to bigger value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@"subviews"` instead of `kCAOnOrderIn`